# Does Java 6 include a program that can run javax.script (Rhino JS) files?

Tags: javascript, java, rhino, java-6

I found that Java 6 includes Rhino JS (except for one or two minor pieces), as `javax.script`.  Pretty cool!

Does a Java 6 install (JRE or JDK, either) contain a binary that I can simply point to a .js file to run?  (I think it would be great to be able to provide source code for others to read and run, without compilation, and require only that Java be installed.)  Or do I have to build the little [8-line program](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html#evalfile) in the docs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, There's [jrunscript](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jrunscript.html)

Comment: Ah, I must have been looking in the JRE folder by mistake -- it's only in the JDK.  Good enough for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a binary included in the JDK called [jrunscript](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jrunscript.html):

```
wookie@hoth:/usr/local/java/bin$ ./jrunscript 
js> println("This is hello from test.js");
This is hello from test.js
```

Answer (score 0):

On Debian based systems, you can install the Rhino package and access a console application called `js`. From there, you can have all your js files begin with:

```
#/usr/bin/js
```

and set the script to executable to run them directly.